# Find value intersections in multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am well out of my depth here: Can this be done? And if so, what methods should I consider?

I periodically receive a spreadsheet that contains a variable number of sheets.  Each sheet has the same header row, but different values in the rows beneath. In one column is an identifying number that indicates a unique user, and I need to determine if there is an intersection between any of the Identifier columns on those worksheets. Here is a simplified example, in which the first and third worksheet have an intersection of abc789 but there is no intersecting value in Worksheet 2. I want to know when there is an intersection, and between which worksheets:

```
Worksheet 1:

ID_Number
•   abc123
•   abc456
•   abc789

Worksheet 2:

ID_Number
•   abc234
•   abc345
•   abc912

Worksheet 3:

ID_Number
•   abc789
•   abc567
•   abc678
```

If it can be done, I'm suspicious of another problem: doing it in a way that works for 3 sheets today and 10 sheets tomorrow! To answer that question I tried setting variables for an unknown number of columns to compare like this, but clearly failed:

```
Dim iArraySize As Integer
Dim iTabCounter As Integer
Dim iLoopCounter As Integer

iTabCounter = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

For iLoopCounter = 3 To iTabCounter
    iArraySize = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(iLoopCounter).Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Count
    dim aID & iloopcounter as Variant 'this line fails on compile with "expected end of statement" highlighting the ampersand
    aID1 = Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Value
Next iLoopCounter
```

Is this a lost cause? Should I resolve myself to manual examination?

Comment: Do you want to end up with a summary sheet that lists all ids that appear on multiple sheets? What do you mean by intersection?

Comment: just curious, why are you intiliasing the iLoopCounter to 3?

Comment: I would expect the line that failed to fail, the ampersand is a concatenator and I dont think it can be used in this way... why dont you dim them separately and then manupulate them?

Comment: You have undeclared variables (`aID1`) and you're attempting to declare `iloopcounter` twice (because of the reason @leemo indicates, expectedly).  Using `Option Explicit` will help avoid this and force you to write cleaner code.

Comment: To get a summary sheet of IDs that appear on multiple sheets you can use a `Dictionary` object.  Maybe describe a little more detail of what your desired output will be.  I don't think this is a lost cause :)

Comment: @leemo There are two sheets that are not part of the comparison, so Sheet(3) would be the first I need to examine. Also, I conclude you are right that the ampersand is not usable in the way I attempted. I was trying to create a variable for each sheet I had to examine. I'm not sure what you mean by "dim them separately and then manipulate them", will that allow me to create a variable number of variables (one for each sheet) somehow?

Comment: @Head of Catering by intersection I am using the intersection of information sets: what items to the sets have in common.  a summary sheet showing which sheets had IDs in common would be useful, but the minimum is to know which sheets do have IDs in common with other sheets (I need to treat them differently).

Comment: @DavidZemens I will check out the dictionary object.  I had never heard of it before.

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for the link. I checked it out and I think the answer would have been to use line breaks, but someone seems to have fixed the display already.

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for saving me with the edit.  I did not realize I could see the edit history, but just checked it out.  <pre> is exactly what I was trying to figure out last night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will output a list of all ID's that were found more than once and what sheets they were found in on a summary sheet:

```
Sub tgr()

    Const strIDCol As String = "A"
    Const lHeaderRow As Long = 1

    Dim cllIDs As Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim IDCell As Range
    Dim arrUnqIDs(1 To 65000) As Variant
    Dim arrMatches(1 To 65000) As String
    Dim ResultIndex As Long
    Dim lUnqIDCount As Long

    Set cllIDs = New Collection

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        With Range(ws.Cells(lHeaderRow + 1, strIDCol), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, strIDCol).End(xlUp))
            If .Row > lHeaderRow Then
                For Each IDCell In .Cells
                    On Error Resume Next
                    cllIDs.Add IDCell.Text, LCase(IDCell.Text)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If cllIDs.Count > lUnqIDCount Then
                        lUnqIDCount = cllIDs.Count
                        arrUnqIDs(lUnqIDCount) = IDCell.Text
                        arrMatches(lUnqIDCount) = ws.Name
                    Else
                        ResultIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(IDCell.Text, arrUnqIDs, 0)
                        arrMatches(ResultIndex) = arrMatches(ResultIndex) & "|" & ws.Name
                    End If
                Next IDCell
            End If
        End With
    Next ws

    If lUnqIDCount > 0 Then
        With Sheets.Add(Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1))
            With .Range("A1:B1")
                .Value = Array("Intersecting ID's", "Intersected in Sheets...")
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With
            .Range("A2").Resize(lUnqIDCount).Value = Application.Transpose(arrUnqIDs)
            .Range("B2").Resize(lUnqIDCount).Value = Application.Transpose(arrMatches)
            .UsedRange.AutoFilter 2, "<>*|*"
            .UsedRange.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
            .UsedRange.AutoFilter
            .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    End If

    Set cllIDs = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set IDCell = Nothing
    Erase arrUnqIDs
    Erase arrMatches

End Sub
```

Comment: that is a pretty swift solution. I just had to change the strIDCol value to "C" and get rid of the first two worksheets (which were not part of the comparison, but would have skewed the result) and presto: your code delivered me the answer I wanted!  Thanks so much (I would give +1 for this answer, if only I had the reputation, but answer accepted!)  I had never worked with (or heard of) collections before. This was educational as well as useful.

Answer (score 1):

It needs some work but heres a script that will print out all the dupes on all sheets in a column. Its not very robust, you have to specify the range, and it prints everything twice

```
Sub printDupes()
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'go thru each worksheet
        For Each idnumber In ws.Range("A2:A4") 'look at each idnumber in id column in selected worksheet
            For Each otherWs In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'go thru each OTHER worksheet
             If ws.Name <> otherWs.Name Then 'skip it if its the same sheet
                For Each otherIdNumber In otherWs.Range("A2:A4") 'go thru each idnumber in the OTHER worksheet (the one you are comparing to)
                 If otherIdNumber.Value = idnumber.Value Then 'if you find a match
                 Debug.Print idnumber.Value 'print the value
                 Debug.Print otherWs.Name & "!" & otherIdNumber.Address 'print the address of the id we were looking at
                 Debug.Print ws.Name & "!" & idnumber.Address 'print address of the match
                 End If

                Next otherIdNumber
                End If
            Next otherWs

        Next idnumber

    Next ws
End Sub
```

this will work for your particular example, replace A2:A4 with a large range

Comment: Thanks for putting effort into this. It clearly does what I need it to do (at the expense of some paper). If I use this I will have it output on another worksheet and save the printer traffic.  Thanks again!

Comment: definitely, a final version of this script would output the results to a sheet. you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

The following code will display message boxes showing where the same ID numbers are found on diferent worksheets in the workbook. It assumes the identifier column is column A and that there are no blank cells within the data in column A

```
Sub CheckSub()
Const iIDENTIFIER_COLUMN = 1
Dim wsCurrentWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim wsWorksheetToCheck As Worksheet
Dim lCurrentRow As Long
Dim lCheckRow As Long
Dim iWorkbookNumber As Integer
Dim iWorkbookCount As Integer
Dim iCheckbookNumber As Integer

iWorkbookCount = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
For iWorkbookNumber = 1 To iWorkbookCount
    lCurrentRow = 2
    Set wsCurrentWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(iWorkbookNumber)
    Do While wsCurrentWorksheet.Cells(lCurrentRow, iIDENTIFIER_COLUMN).Value <> Empty
        For iCheckbookNumber = iWorkbookNumber To iWorkbookCount
            Set wsWorksheetToCheck = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(iCheckbookNumber)
            If wsCurrentWorksheet.Name <> wsWorksheetToCheck.Name Then
                lCheckRow = 2
                Do While wsWorksheetToCheck.Cells(lCheckRow, iIDENTIFIER_COLUMN).Value <> Empty
                    If wsCurrentWorksheet.Cells(lCurrentRow, iIDENTIFIER_COLUMN).Value = _
                        wsWorksheetToCheck.Cells(lCheckRow, iIDENTIFIER_COLUMN).Value Then
                            MsgBox (wsCurrentWorksheet.Cells(lCurrentRow, iIDENTIFIER_COLUMN).Value _
                            & " found on " & wsCurrentWorksheet.Name & " and " & wsWorksheetToCheck.Name)
                    End If
                    lCheckRow = lCheckRow + 1
                Loop
            End If
        Next iCheckbookNumber
        lCurrentRow = lCurrentRow + 1
    Loop
Next iWorkbookNumber
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I did test it, and it did work as advertised after I changed the iIDENTIFIER_COLUMN to 3 to match my data, and changed all instances of `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook`.